# ios: How to segue from detail to table view programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I'm sure that can be done simply, but i haven't find any information about that. So the question is in title: How can i segue back from detail to table view pro-grammatically (when something happens i call a method which returns to `UITableView` ).

Comment: It depends on how you got to the detail view.  Post some code of how your view flow happens and we can make it un-happen.

Comment: I'm not shore what do u mean as "view flow" but it is just a push-segue from UITableViewCell

Comment: Try this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035809/pop-the-current-view-using-segues-storyboard-on-ios-5

Comment: try [unwind segue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509422/how-to-perform-unwind-segue-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did a segue-> push you can return in the detail view controller by

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You don't need a segue for this, it is just reversing the push.

Answer (score 0):

When you have view controllers its either OliverM's solution or if you are not working on a navigation controller its

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

where completion can be a block where actions can be defined to do after the controller was dismissed