# viewDidLoad happens on every return to first view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewdidload, navigationcontroller

I'm working with three view contollers, the first called "`menuVC`" embedded in a `navigation controller`, and then "`viewVC`" and "`resultsVC`". I'm using `push segues` from VC to VC.

Now, my problem is, that every time I return to the first "`menuVC`" from the last "resultsVC", both `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` is envoked. As far as I can read everywhere, a `navigation` `controller` scene with `push` `segues` will never "`pop`" the `rootviewcontroller`, or any view controller for that matter, when I use push segues...? Or is there something I'm missing?

So, my question is - why is my first view controller "`MenuVC`" loading a new instance every time, when I should actually just be returning to the same instance of the "`MenuVC`"?

Comment: How u come back to menuVC from resultVC.Ur flow is like menuVC->push->viewVC->push->resultVC , r8?

Comment: if you push your view every time then it will load new instance everytime so try popping the view controller.Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035809/pop-the-current-view-using-segues-storyboard-on-ios-5

Comment: @Suhail > Yes, exactly. And from resultVC->any of the two.

Comment: @xphobia > Thanks, yes. I'll try it out. But popping a view controller removes stuff, doesn't it? My problem is that I need a VC not to be removed...

Answer (score 0):

```
it depends on how to came back to the rootview controller from the last view controller. 
 you  should better use 

 UIViewController *vc=[nav viewControllers].lastObject;

 [vc.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
```

Comment: I'm moving from VC to VC with [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"returnToVC" sender:self]. I'm not moving to "last object" - just to one of the other VC's.

Comment: Okay, I tried to make a class for my navigation controller, but the program totally freaked. I guess that is not something you just do. But I can see, that I need to organize my views somehow. Can you give me a simple advice about that?

Comment: Ok, after a couple days my concrete brain is slowly getting it... thanks for helping! I was having trouble with both my viewdidload and viewdidappear, but I think it's soon in place.