# How to go back to the initial viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

i have two view controller namely, "ViewController" and "ProcessingViewController". "ViewController" has two textfields and a button, while "ProcessingViewController" has a textfield.

when the button in "ViewController" is pressed, a segue will be triggered in "prepareForSegue" to start "ProcessingViewController". in "ProcessingViewController", some processing will be done and when finished I should go back to "ViewController".

the question is, how should I go back to ViewController from ProcesingViewController?

**note**:

I added a segue from ViewController to ProcessingViewController in the storyBoard, and I override prepareForeSegue method in ViewControoler

**code**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

 NSLog(@"ProcessingViewController->before processing data: %@", 
 self.data);

self.data = @(self.data.integerValue * 10);

NSLog(@"ProcessingViewController->after processing data: %@", 
self.data);
[_textFieldValueToBeProcessed setText:[self.data stringValue]];
[self.delegate processFinished:self.data];

//[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**storyboard**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="12121" systemVersion="16F73" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
<device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
    <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
</device>
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="12089"/>
    <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="EgF-YL-wkx">
                            <rect key="frame" x="123" y="386" width="129" height="90"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <state key="normal" title="send"/>
                            <connections>
                                <segue destination="Z1r-zV-tYu" kind="show" identifier="segueTransitToProcessingViewController" id="8OJ-jg-a4A"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="value to send" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NGQ-pY-0eN">
                            <rect key="frame" x="48" y="202" width="279" height="30"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                        </textField>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="value received" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="G88-eJ-Q35">
                            <rect key="frame" x="48" y="276" width="279" height="30"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                        </textField>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="btnStartTransition" destination="EgF-YL-wkx" id="e07-ay-ZGi"/>
                    <outlet property="textFieldValueToBeProcessed" destination="NGQ-pY-0eN" id="RKE-Ag-AbW"/>
                    <outlet property="textFieldVlueAfterProcessing" destination="G88-eJ-Q35" id="Ih5-ih-I6p"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="116" y="123.68815592203899"/>
    </scene>
    <!--Processing View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="Txs-Cf-DUX">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="Z1r-zV-tYu" customClass="ProcessingViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="SNI-e8-8lZ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="De6-we-dka"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="DME-Ab-bxq">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="received value after processing" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bcF-KR-LLP">
                            <rect key="frame" x="50" y="318" width="238" height="30"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                        </textField>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="textFieldValueToBeProcessed" destination="bcF-KR-LLP" id="fgE-IT-PWg"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="TXj-sv-7ZF" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="860" y="123.68815592203899"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
```

Comment: you need a segue back to your ViewController

Comment: can you add your storyboard scene

Comment: are you embed your ViewController in navigation controller, how will you navigate from ViewController to ProcessingViewController , can you add some code related to this or else UI design

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I added the storyboard

Comment: @user2121 - if you press the done button call the method as `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` for go back to viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

> If you have used Modal Segue

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //Swift

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //Obj-C
```

> If you have used Navigation Segue

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) //Swift

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]; //Obj-C

//To pop all the view controllers between the last and root.

self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true) //Swift

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated: YES]; //Obj-C
```

To understand more, [Pop the current view using Segues/Storyboard on iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035809/pop-the-current-view-using-segues-storyboard-on-ios-5)

Comment: actually, I tried both solutions you provided but the second VC doesn't go back to the 1st

Comment: Easiest way is an unwind segue. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

If in your stack is limited to these two controllers, then when you press a button in "ViewController", you could **present modally** using a segue and when you are done with processing in "ProcessingViewController", you can dismiss it using **dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion**:.

If however, you plan to use a **Show/Push segue**, you will need to embed your initial view controller "ViewController" in a UINavigationViewController and then when you are done processing in "ProcessingViewController", you can use an instance of that to pop to the initial view controller using **popViewControllerAnimated:**

**EDIT**
@user2121 - You will first need to embed your initial ViewController "ViewController" in your storyboard and embed it in a UINavigationController. 
**Go to Storyboard -> Select your ViewController -> Editor Menu -> Embed In -> NavigationController **

Then in "ProcessingViewController" use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]

Comment: i change the segue type to present modally, and I used your code but it is not working..would you please have a look at the code above

Comment: You are not required to use a navigation controller. The best way would be to use an unwind segue. See my answer below

Comment: Did you call **dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion** after all processing in the "ProcessingViewController" was finished?////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //Swift/////////////////////////////////////‌​////////////////////‌​///////////////////////////////////

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //Obj-C

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an unwind segue.

From a previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12843906/6622117) :

"Step 1)

Go to the code for the "Previous" view controller that you wish to unwind to and add this:

Objective-C

```
- (IBAction)unwindToThisViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    //nothing goes here, unless you want to perform some other actions on unwind
}
```

Be sure to also declare this method in your .h file in Obj-C

Step 2)

In storyboard, go to your "Current" view controller (aka, the view that you want to unwind from) and simply drag a segue from your button or whatever up to the little orange "EXIT" icon at the top right of your source view.

[image]

There should now be an option to connect to "`- unwindToThisViewController`"

That's it, your segue will unwind when your button is tapped."

Comment: I did as you explained in your ab´answer, but now the problem is when I ctrl+drage the button to the EXIT icon, the EXIT icon is never highlighted and consequently I do not get the menu that display the method of the unwind segue "-unwindToThisViewController"..please le t em know how to solve this issue